# uploading file from backberry to web service = JVM error 104 Uncaught NullPointerException?

Tags: web-services, blackberry, ksoap2

I am developing a small blackberry project.

Here are the step that it is supposed to be:

1. User clicks Speak! button. The application record speech voice. [No Problem]
2. When user finishes speaking, click Stop! button. Once the stop button is clicked, the speech voice will be saved on BB as an AMR file. Then, the file will be sent to web service via ksoap2. Web service will return response as a string of file name. The problem is **web service return nothing and there is an error occur: JVM error 104: Uncaught NullPointerException** I wonder if I placed the code on the right place, or I did something wrong with ksoap2??

here is the code for web service

```
namespace VoiceServer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Converting AMR to WAV
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        public string UploadFile(String receivedByte, String location, String fileName)
{
    String filepath = fileName;

/*don't worry about receivedByte and location, I will work on them after the problem is     solved :) */

    return "Success"+filepath;
}

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Below is the code running on Eclipse, I'm not sure if I placed the code for sending file to web service on the right place.

```
public class MyAudio extends MainScreen {
private ButtonField _startRecordingButton;
private ButtonField _stopRecordingButton;
private HorizontalFieldManager _fieldManagerButtons;
private VoiceNotesRecorderThread _voiceRecorder;
private LabelField _myAudioTextField;
private DateField hourMin;
private long _initTime;

public MyAudio() {
    _startRecordingButton = new ButtonField("Speak!", ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
    _stopRecordingButton = new ButtonField("Stop!", ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
    _fieldManagerButtons = new  HorizontalFieldManager();
    _voiceRecorder = new VoiceNotesRecorderThread(500000,"file:///store/home/user/voicefile.amr",this);
    _voiceRecorder.start();

    myButtonFieldChangeListener buttonFieldChangeListener = new myButtonFieldChangeListener();
    _startRecordingButton.setChangeListener(buttonFieldChangeListener);     
    _stopRecordingButton.setChangeListener(buttonFieldChangeListener);      

    _fieldManagerButtons.add(_startRecordingButton);
    _fieldManagerButtons.add(_stopRecordingButton);

    _myAudioTextField = new LabelField(" Welcome to VoiceSMS!!!" );
    add(_fieldManagerButtons);
    add(_myAudioTextField);

    SimpleDateFormat sdF = new SimpleDateFormat("ss");
    hourMin = new DateField("", 0, sdF);
    hourMin.setEditable(false);
    hourMin.select(false);
    _initTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    add(hourMin);
}

public void setAudioTextField(String text) {
    _myAudioTextField.setText(text);
}

public void startTime() {
    _initTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    hourMin.setDate(0);
}

public void updateTime() {
    hourMin.setDate((System.currentTimeMillis()-_initTime));
}

class myButtonFieldChangeListener implements FieldChangeListener{
    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        if(field == _startRecordingButton) {
            try {
                _voiceRecorder.startRecording();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else if(field == _stopRecordingButton) {
            _voiceRecorder.stopRecording();

            //----------Send AMR to Web Service-------------//

            Object response = null;
            String URL = "http://http://localhost:portnumber/Service1.asmx";
            String method = "UploadFile";
            String NameSpace = "http://tempuri.org/";
            FileConnection fc = null;
            byte [] ary = null;
            try 
            {
            fc = (FileConnection)Connector.open("file:///store/home/user/voicefile.amr",Connector.READ_WRITE);
            int size = (int) fc.fileSize();
            //String a = Integer.toString(size);
            //Dialog.alert(a);
            ary = new byte[size];
            fc.openDataInputStream().read(ary);
            fc.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e1) 
            {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            SoapObject client = new SoapObject(NameSpace,method);
            client.addProperty("receivedByte",new SoapPrimitive(SoapEnvelope.ENC,"base64",Base64.encode(ary)));
            client.addProperty("location","Test/");
            client.addProperty("fileName","file:///store/home/user/voicefile.amr");
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.bodyOut = client;
            HttpTransport http = new HttpTransport(URL);

            try 
            {
            http.call(method,envelope);
            }
            catch(InterruptedIOException io)
            {
            io.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
            System.err.println(e);
            }
            catch (XmlPullParserException e) 
            {
            System.err.println(e);

            }
            catch(OutOfMemoryError e)
            {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try 
            {
            response = envelope.getResponse();
            Dialog.alert(response.toString());
            }
            catch (SoapFault e) 
            {
            System.err.println(e);
            System.out.println("Soap Fault");
            }
            catch(NullPointerException ne)
            {
            System.err.println(ne);
            }
            Dialog.alert(response.toString());
            //Dialog.alert("Send Success");

            //----------End of Upload-to-Web-Service--------//
        }           
    }
}
}
```

I don't know if the file is not sent to web service, or web service has got the file and produce no response??? I am a real newbie for BB programming. Please let me know if I did anything wrong.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo in your URL variable value.

"http://" typed twice

String URL = "http://http://localhost:portnumber/Service1.asmx";

Answer (score 0):

Hooray!!! Problem Solved!

just changed URL as Rafael suggested and added [WebMethod] above "public string UploadFile" in the web service code